# JSoup can't load a website fast enough, but only for me

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, jsoup

I am making an android app that scrapes a certain website content and puts it into a list. Lately, I've had an error show up where the Document ( JScoup class ) didn't contain certain elements all of a sudden. I printed the entire document and this is what I got:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    function leastFactor(n) {
    if (isNaN(n) || !isFinite(n)) return NaN;
    if (typeof phantom !== 'undefined') return 'phantom';
    if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) return 'node';
    if (n==0) return 0;
    if (n%1 || n*n<2) return 1;
    if (n%2==0) return 2;
    if (n%3==0) return 3;
    if (n%5==0) return 5;
    var m=Math.sqrt(n);
    for (var i=7;i<=m;i+=30) {
        if (n%i==0)      return i;
        if (n%(i+4)==0)  return i+4;
        if (n%(i+6)==0)  return i+6;
        if (n%(i+10)==0) return i+10;
        if (n%(i+12)==0) return i+12;
        if (n%(i+16)==0) return i+16;
        if (n%(i+22)==0) return i+22;
        if (n%(i+24)==0) return i+24;
    }
    return n;
    }
    function go() {
     var p=2456313912482; var s=1782578125; var n;
    if ((s >> 3) & 1)/* 120886108*
    */p+=293087928*/* 120886108*
    */4;/*
    *13;
    */else 
    p-=/* 120886108*
    */202819457*/*
    *13;
    */4;/*
    *13;
    */if ((s >> 1) & 1)
    p+=296193202*/*
    else p-=
    */2;/*
    else p-=
    */else /* 120886108*
    */p-=812964012*2;/*
    p+= */if ((s >> 0) & 1) p+=/*
    p+= */548319846* 3;/*
    p+= */else /*
    p+= */p-=/*
    *13;
    */1210867650*
    1;/* 120886108*
    */if ((s >> 8) & 1) p+=
    151523417*  11;
    else /*
    *13;
    */p-= 212850085*    9;/* 120886108*
    */if ((s >> 4) & 1) p+=/*
    else p-=
    */81741529*
    7;/*
    *13;
    */else /*
    *13;
    */p-=/*
    p+= */18587493*
    5;/*
    else p-=
    */ p-=4349934143;
     n=leastFactor(p);
    { document.cookie="duplexdataiad="+n+"*"+p/n+":"+s+":2100623372:1;path=/;";
      document.location.reload(true); }
    }
//--></script>
</head> 
<body onload="go()">
   Loading...  
</body>
```

Apparently, `<body>` is still loading when JSoup scrapes it. What's weird about this is that it only happens sometimes, and when it happens, it only happens to me and only on my internet connection (Ethernet, wifi, neither works), but as soon as I turn on mobile data on my phone and I try to test the app, it suddenly works perfectly. My friend, who is also developing this app with me, had this issue once, a while back, but after that time never. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely some sort of anti-bot mechanism has detected you and is serving you up bad pages. Hence why it works from one internet connection fine but not the other. I suspect you're IP/some other bit of data/fingerprint has been logged somewhere and being treated as a bot. Really all you can do is slow down your scraping so you're not treated as a bot, OR flip between connections to try and evade detection.

If you try from your browser on what is the 'bad' internet connection, does it work?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you think that if someone else uses the app on their phone, they could also potentially get this error as well just from JSoup scraping the webpage?

Comment: The website loads normally, yes.

Comment: Perhaps your requests have been finger printed and blocked if the browser works - look at the headers your browser sets. Typically `Referer` and cookies are used to track session sometimes the `user-agent` is used - if you can replicate what your browser would send for a new session (hint: delete cookies each time - there are browser addons for cookies), you can trace the http calls made + headers/cookies sent between the client/server to replicate the flow. Then you won't get blocked